Get only one matching file in a directory using find
Is it possible to look for files using find and match only one in a given directory (no matter which) and ignore the rest?
Here's an example of a dir struct:
A/
├─ foo_a1
├─ foo_a2
├─ foo_a3
C/
├─ D/
│  ├─ B/
│  │  ├─ foo_b1
│  │  ├─ foo_b2
├─ E/
│  ├─ foo_e1
│  ├─ foo_e2

I hope to get the following list:
A/foo_{a1 XOR a2 XOR a3}
C/D/B/foo_{b1 XOR b2}
C/E/foo_{e1 OR e2}

I can match every file starting with foo and then post-process results but I'm wondering if there is any way to do it using find only. Please note after foo any pattern may occur.

Based on this answer there would be this find . -type d -exec find {} -depth -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'foo_*' -print -quit \; command. Does that fit your needs?

@tobifasc : -quit makes find stop immediately. It would print one directory in total, instead of one matching file per directory.

How to make find only traverse a directories. For each directory, let -exec call a small shell script, which then would print one of the files matching the pattern, or nothing if no file matches.

@user1934428 you're missing that the -quit is called in a child find not the parent find

@jjhnc : Indeed, I missed the nested find. Interesting idea!

No, it is not possible to use find by itself to do what you want.
It is necessary to store state indicating whether or not an appropriate file has already been seen. However, without calling out to another program, find has nowhere to save or retrieve that state.
If you have GNU find which has -quit, you can cheat by calling out to find itself, but that will be inefficient:
find TOP -type d -exec \
    find {} -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'foo*' -print -quit \;


Could you elaborate on "If you have GNU grep which has -quit,..."? I don't understand how grep comes into play here

He means GNU find...

@dawg oops, not sure how that happened. thanks for fixing

btw, -maxdepth 1 is also non-standard. I initially used the equivalent \( -path {} -o -prune \) but if using GNU find, may as well use its other exhancements

given how concise a solution using this method is, the inefficiency may be a reasonable tradeoff, especially as it probably only makes a difference for huge trees (and postprocessing may end up being expensive anyway - one would need to benchmark performance for any particular situation). however, if a particular file is needed (eg. repeatability. oldest, alphabetically first, or some other critera) then postprocessing may be more sensible since find will select an arbitrary file (probably based on the order that readdir(3) returns items)

Suppose you have this file tree:
$ tree .
.
├── A
│   ├── foo_a1
│   ├── foo_a2
│   └── foo_a3
└── C
    ├── D
    │   └── B
    │       ├── foo_b1
    │       └── foo_b2
    └── E
        ├── foo_e1
        └── foo_e2

I would just roll up my sleeves with two nested loops to walk the tree directory by directory:
#!/bin/bash

rand_files=()
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' dn; do    
    files=()
    while IFS=  read -r -d $'\0'; do
        files+=("$REPLY")
    # add "-name foo* if you only want the foo files
    done < <(find "$dn" -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0)
    (( ${#files[@]} == 0 )) && continue
    rand_files+=("${files[ $RANDOM % ${#files[@]} ]}")
done < <(find . -type d -print0)

#Test what we got: 
declare -p rand_files

Prints:
declare -a rand_files=([0]="./A/foo_a2" [1]="./C/D/B/foo_b2" [2]="./C/E/foo_e1")

This prints a RANDOM file from each directory with files. If you only want the first or last file, could be modified to:
rand_files+=("${files[0]}") #LAST file from each directory

rand_files+=("${files[${#files[@]} - 1]}") #FIRST


Alternatively, you can write and export a function for each directory and execute that once find finds a directory:
function dir_func() {
    shopt -s nullglob dotglob
    files=()
    for f in "$@"/foo*; do
        files+=("$f")
    done    
    (( ${#files[@]} == 0 )) || \
        printf "%s\n" "${files[ $RANDOM % ${#files[@]} ]}"
}
export -f dir_func

find . -type d -print0 | xargs -n1 -0 bash -c 'dir_func "$@"' --

Prints:
./A/foo_a3
./C/D/B/foo_b2
./C/E/foo_e1

Finally, on GNU or BSD find, you can nest the finds with quit. This is a non POSIX extension:
find . -type d -exec find {} -depth -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "foo*" -print -quit \; 

Prints:
./A/foo_a3
./C/D/B/foo_b2
./C/E/foo_e2


Since this is tagged as bash, With find and bash.
find . -type d -exec bash -O nullglob -O dotglob -c '
  d=("$1"/*/); ((${#d[@]} == 0)) || exit; d=("$1"/foo_*); echo "${d[0]}"' bash {} ';'


Instead of echo  of "${d[0]}", one could probably use RANDOM for printing the value
echo "${d[RANDOM % ${#d[@]}]}"


With SRANDOM
echo "${d[SRANDOM % ${#d[@]}]}"

